# Make trigger with variables work for multiple row inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-insert

I have a warehouse database and want to implement a trigger which makes sure that the number of products returned by customers cannot exceed the number of products sold minus the number of products returned previously.

It works for one insert in the RETURNS table, but gives me an error if I insert multiple rows at once.

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

The tables affected are

- SALES_ITEMS (PRODUCT, SALE, SALES_QUANTITY)
- RETURNS (IDRETURN, PRODUCT, SALE, RETURN_QUANTITY)

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr
ON Returns
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @product INTEGER;
    DECLARE @sale INTEGER;

    SET @product = (SELECT PRODUCT FROM Inserted); 
    SET @sale = (SELECT SALE FROM Inserted); 

    IF (SELECT SUM(r.RETURN_QUANTITY) 
        FROM RETURNS r 
        WHERE r.PRODUCT = @product 
          AND r.SALE = @sale) > (SELECT s.SALES_QUANTITY 
                                 FROM SALE_ITEMS s 
                                 WHERE s.PRODUCT = @product AND s.SALE = @sale)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END
END
```

Comment: What's the error???

Comment: You need to switch you mind into set based thinking... triggers in SQL Server use the Inserted and Deleted pseudo-tables which you use just as you would use any other table in any other query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . this is a bit complicated.  One method is to join the returns and sales together to see if there are any cases where the returns exceed the sales:

```
if exists (select 1
           from RETURNS r join
                inserted i
                on r.PRODUCT = i.product and r.SALE = i.sale join
                sales_items si
                on si.product = i.product and si.sale = i.sale
           group by r.product, s.sales_quantity
           having sum(r.return_quantity) > s.sales_quantity
          )
begin
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
end;
```

Comment: @Hackerman . . . You are saying that you can have multiple rows inserting on the same product?  The `group by` should be isolating the total for each product from each other.